# iOS - Why is init necessary and other init questions

Tags: ios

Objective C spec (from Apple) Page 49 states that 
**Every Class that declares an instance variable must provide an init method to initialize them**

My questions - 
Why is this necessary?  Doesn't NSObject initialize the iVar's for a instance?

Should one think of init as a constructor.

Does init have to be called init? Can I do 
id anObject  = [[SomeClass alloc] **foo**];

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

The init method is similar to a constructor, but it's not automatically called. You must call it yourself.

Calling it "init" is a common convention, but not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The default `init` of `NSObject` won't touch your **instance variable**. The statement from spec means that if you are using something like `NSString *str` or `NSDate *d` objects as instance variable of the class, you are responsible for initializing it. And this typically happen in `init`, though you can initialize them in other methods.

And yes you can have `[[SomeClass alloc] foo]` returning an object.

Comment: `-foo` would not be a static method, if `alloc` returns an instance of that class...

Answer (score 0):

Classes typically don't know about the internals of their sub-classes and NSObject is no different in that way.

`alloc` + `init` is very like a constructor except that chaining isn't automatic.

It doesn't have to be called `init`, but having it start with `init` is almost universal.
E.g.:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.myString = string;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly It is not necessary.`init` is used to initialize properties of instance variable. you don't evoke the init which will be ok when you use your own class.In my opinion,`alloc` equals the `constructor`.Through a very simple example I told the reason.when we want to use singleton pattern,it is very easy to complement in java or other programming language with `constructor`.It is easy too in Object C or IOS in object c,though there is no distinct constructor.In Apple's official example，you will find that they just rewrite the `allocWithZone` in NSObject and the alloc will evoke it finally.So I think the `alloc` is the constructor in Object C.However I think you'd better to use the init.It is convention or standard.So the book use the word `must`.No matter what programming language initialization must be done.Just Apple emphasize it  explicitly